# Set suspend idle delay time on terminal on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: suspend, time, idle

How can I set idle delay time on Ubuntu 18.04 suspend on terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To set AC time out, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout <VALUE>
```

In place of `<VALUE>` put time in seconds, e.g.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 3600
```

Similarly, to set laptop battery timeout, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout <VALUE>
```

Comment: i tried running your suggested command but suspend idle time still not changing.

Comment: @crltzn 18.04 is still beta, expected that some things will not work. To help the developers fix this issue, you may consider reporting a bug at launchpad.net. Also check whether "suspend" is activated by running `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type` (for AC) and `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type` (for battery).

Comment: still good on 20.04